# How to use the MatTableDataSource with an observable?

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable, angular8, angular-material-table

I am using the mat-table and I am trying to use the *MatTableDataSource* with an observable (I get the data from a web service), but I don't know how to configure the *MatTableDataSource* to use an observable instead of an array.

Is the only solution to this problem, to subscribe to the observable in the *ngOnInit* method and always create a new MatTableDataSource when new data arrives?

This is what I have until now, but I don't know if this is the correct solution for working with the *MatTableDataSource* with an observable.

```js
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Thing>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
    
ngOnInit() {
    getThings().subscribe(things => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(things);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this is correct solution as per Angular Material documentation. If you want to store data into dataSource then you have to use new MatTableDataSource()

Comment: See my answer on this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691541/how-to-enable-sorting-in-angular-material-data-table-when-the-datasource-is-obs/69329180#69329180

It is completely possible to use an observable with MatTableDataSource

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should be able to new up the `MatTableDataSource` once at the class level and then use the `data` setter in `ngOnInit`.

```js
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Thing>();
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit() {
    getThings().subscribe(things => {
        this.dataSource.data = things;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
}
```

Comment: Please note that it's quite a bit slower to set the sort after setting data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51296374/1596352

(in my own app, it hasn't been quite as extreme as in the link, but still made a noticeable difference.

Comment: Yes, i suggest to put the subscription under the `ngAfterViewInit` function. :D

Comment: What if I don't want to subscribe to it in the component and use async in the template to get the data?

Comment: setting paginator and sort MUST be done in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: How's that the answer to a question on using Observable!?

Answer (score 38):

### Use MatTableDataSource as Observable

You can just `pipe` your observable:

```js
thingsAsMatTableDataSource$: Observable<MatTableDataSource<Thing>>  =
  getThings().pipe(
    map(things => {
      const dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Thing>();
      dataSource.data = things;
      return dataSource;
}));
```

You can use an async pipe on your observable in the template:

```html
[dataSource]="thingsAsMatTableDataSource$ | async"
```

*This way you do not have to subscribe, and can still enjoy mat-table sorting etc...*

### Prevent Repeated Constructor Calls

Just instantiate it once as a private member and use that instead:

```js
private dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Thing>();

thingsAsMatTableDataSource$: Observable<MatTableDataSource<Thing>>  =
  getThings().pipe(
    map(things => {
      const dataSource = this.dataSource;
      dataSource.data = things
      return dataSource;
}));
```

Here's a simple example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bqhro2?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: This seems to be the  tidiest, safest and most idiomatic approach, and I can confirm that it works. I'm surprised it has so few upvotes.

Comment: Thanks it work but can't use Observable<MatTableDataSource<Thing>> can use Observable<any> Error as below

 Type 'MatTableDataSource<Service> | null' is not assignable to type 'CdkTableDataSourceInput<Service>'.

Comment: I try to use this solution, But getting this error in the HTML file: Type 'MatTableDataSource<Thing> | null' is not assignable to type 'CdkTableDataSourceInput<Thing>'. You know why?

Comment: Same problem here as @PuneetSharma and levi... updating this answer would be great

Comment: You can either make sure you are always returning the expected object, by returning a default empty source, or just make it of type `MatTableDataSource<Thing> | null`. But in the second case your template should be able to handle null values.

Comment: I'm using this solution also with `paginator` and `sort` and everything works like a charm. But, I'd like to use `filter` (based on input value) but have no idea, how to 'merge' the filter string with the `dataSource.merge` property.

Comment: to get reed of this error, in you template make sure datasource is not null
`<table *ngIf="thingsAsMatTableDataSource$ | async as DS" mat-table [dataSource]="DS" ...`

Answer (score 7):

this is a workaround, because MatTableDataSource doesn't support Observable as data source

```
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { SomeInterface} from './some.interface';

export class CustomDataSource extends MatTableDataSource<SomeInterface> {

    private collection: SomeInterface[] = [];

    private collection$: Subscription;

    constructor(collection: Observable<SomeInterface[]>) {
        super();
        this.collection$ = collection.subscribe(data => {
           this.data = data; // here you have to adjust the behavior as needed
        });
    }

   disconnect() {
     this.collection$.unsubscribe();
     super.disconnect();
   }
}
```

then in component:

```
dataSource: CustomDataSource;

ngOnInit(): void {
  const observableData$ = getData();
  this.dataSource = new CustomDataSource(observableData$);
  // this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; // add sorting or filter
}
```

example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-seskzc?)

Comment: can you add some explanations to your code ?

Comment: i made some changes in my post and i added example on stackblitz

Answer (score 3):

You can use an observable too, just (*)

```
[dataSource]="dataSource|async"
```

(*) really you needn't use the pipe async

See an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6fomv1?file=app/table-basic-example.html), where I replace the first example of the doc by

```
dataSource = of(ELEMENT_DATA).pipe(delay(1000));
```

Comment: But then it is not that easy to use the sorting and pagination features.

Comment: sorry, you're ok, dataSource can be, a MatTableDataSource, and array or an observable, but you only can sort it if is a MatTableDataSource;

Answer (score 2):

I've released a library for that: `@matheo/datasource`

I explain the basic concepts in this article:
https://medium.com/@matheo/reactive-datasource-for-angular-1d869b0155f6

and in the example code, you can see how I fetch items from a Firebase database and manipulate the pagination. sorting and filters in the example repo
I hope that you like it and give me your opinion about it ;)

Comment: Your example at Stackblitz doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`<mat-table [dataSource]="(things$ | async) ?? []">`

````
  things$: Observable<MatTableDataSource<Thing>> =
    this.thingService.getThings().pipe(map(things => new MatTableDataSource<Thing>(things))); ``` 

with this approach async pipe and MatTableDataSource works without error. Sort and pagination can be used afterwards.
````