# How to fix ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'sort') in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to implement a sort on a Mat Table. While the sort does work as intended it throws the following error because it is trying to apply the sort before the object is defined:
**core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'sort')**

I've tried moving the `this.sort` from the ngOnInit and ngOnChanges. When I do this, the errors go away, but then the sort doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
    import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { UserService } from 'src/app/shared/services/user.service';
    import { ParsedWidget } from '../../models/parsed-widget.model';
    import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';
    import { CriteriaService } from '../../services/criteria.service';
    import { SuperWidgetComponent } from '../super-widget/super-widget.component';
    import { DateService } from 'src/app/shared/services/date.service';
    import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
    import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

    export interface ctList {
      NAME: string;
      ID: string;
      CODE: string;
      P_NAME: string;
      PR_NAME: string;
      Hub: string;
      DATE: string;
      CODE_MJR: string;
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-ct-table-data',
      templateUrl: './ct-table-data.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./ct-table-data.component.css']
    })

    export class CtTableDataComponent extends SuperWidgetComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {
      @Input() metadata: ParsedWidget; //THis is the data coming from the parent component. Use @Output to pass from child to parent
      @Input() data: any;
      
      loading: boolean = false;
      viewDrilldown:boolean = false;
      ctList: any;
      
      displayedColumns: string[] = [
          'ID', 
          'Name',
          'CODE', 
          'P_NAME',
          'PR_NAME',
          'CODE_MJR',
          'DATE',
          'Hub'    
      ];
      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ctList>;
      
      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
      
      constructor(
        public apiService:ApiService,
        private dateService: DateService,) {
        super(apiService)
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
      
      ngOnChanges(){          
        if (this.data) {
          this.getctsri(this.data);
        } 
        else 
        { 
          this.getcts(this.data);
        }
      }
      
       ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
      
       applyFilter(event: Event) {
        const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
      }

      convertToFullDate(datestring: string) {
        if (datestring) {
          let value = this.dateService.convertToFullDate(datestring);
          return value
        }
        else {
          return datestring
        }
      }

      async getcts(theCriteria: any){
        await super.post('common/spgetcts',theCriteria,'api')//this runs the sql
        this.data= this.apiPostResponse.data;//This assigns the sql return values to a variable
        this.ctList = this.data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }

      async getctsri(theCriteria: any) {
        await super.post('common/spgetctseng',theCriteria,'api')//this runs the sql
        this.data = this.apiPostResponse.data;//This assigns the sql return values to a variable
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
    }
```

**UPDATE: 1-18-2022**

I have tried adding in `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ctList>();` as suggested below, but while it removes the error, the sorting stops working.

I added in some logging and this is what I have seen:
ngOnChanges 
getctsristart - Logs when it starts this function
ngoninit - throws error because datasource has not yet been initialized from getctsri.
getsriend - datasource has been initialized with data. 
ngAfterViewInit - No error thrown. 
Sorting works as it should.

If I remove either or both of the `this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;` from ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit the sort no longer works.

How can I get the sort to work AND get rid of the error message?

Comment: Can you post the part of the template that uses this `sort`?

Comment: Maybe only keep the 'sort code' in the ngAfterViewInit()?

Comment: @Hypenate - This doesn't work. I have to have it in both for the sort to work at all.

Comment: @Luiz - It is a standard angular material. This is the table def: <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>  and this is a header def: <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>

Comment: Try to add a div with `*ngIf="dataSource"` or maybe use `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ctList>();` as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770423/how-to-use-the-mattabledatasource-with-an-observable

Comment: `dataSource` is undefined at ngOnInit since you've only done this: `dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ctList>;`